# CSS oblique line in the middle of the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I am trying to get a oblique line in the middle of the screen and when you hover a part it should grow (which I will know how to make, I guess).

The problem is getting the oblique line in the center of the screen and make it responsive.

This is my current code:

https://jsfiddle.net/kh657fL2/

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML/CSS slicing!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="block block-red">
            Demo
        </div>

        <div class="block block-green">
            Demo
        </div>

        <script src="ui.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}


.block {
    height: 100vh;
    width: calc(50% - 100px);
    position: relative;
}

.block-red {
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}

.block-green {
    background-color:#00ff00;
    float:right;
}

.block:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    content:'';
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    background: inherit;
}
.block-red:after {
    right: 0;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
     z-index: -1;
}
.block-green:after {
    left: 0;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
     z-index: 2;
}
```

It looks right but it is not responsive on mobile devices - there is a white space between the colors and it is not always in the center of the screen. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to calculate half of the width of your window, minus 20% of most of the height.

CSS:

```
width: calc(50% - (90vh * 0.2));
```

Then you just need to calculate double the width for your skewed element:

```
width: calc(100vw * 2);
```

**Bonus:**
You could add this jQuery to center things for tall, narrow windows:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var width = $(window).width();
  var height = $(window).height();
  var diff = ((width - (height * 0.37)) / 2);

  if (width < (height * 0.37)) {
    $('.block').css('left', - diff);
  } else {
    $('.block').css('left', '0');
  }
});
```

Working example:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kh657fL2/3/)

**Update:**
If you want to animate the width on hover, you can do that with a CSS transition.

```
transition: 1s ease-in-out;
```

Hover animation example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kh657fL2/12/)

Comment: only one issue now. How can i detect a hover over the :after part? i need to make it grow on hover but jquery doesn't detect the after part :(

Comment: What about just doing that with the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class? Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kh657fL2/4/)

Comment: I know i tried that aswell but it needs to be smooth so i added a transition but that doesn;t work since the z-index needs to be changed and hovering directly from left to right bugs i am trying to solve this with jquery https://jsfiddle.net/kh657fL2/5/

Comment: current code: https://jsfiddle.net/kh657fL2/6/ almost done but still contains bugs :(

Comment: This should work: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kh657fL2/7/)**.  I would still recommend doing it with CSS because the result is cleaner. I've removed the z-index swap and we are just changing the green width.

Comment: trevorp thanks for all your help but testing this on full screen makes the red part glitch when holding the mouse on the green part. sorry for all my questions!

Comment: And green moves way more than red on a small screen

Comment: Here you go: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kh657fL2/11/).  I've updated the red layer's css (to fix the glitch on green hover) and I've updated the width calculation for the green hover.